Expired Patents - Can I file?
I want to file for a PPA but a patent of the same idea has already been granted a patent but has expired due to nonpayment of maintenance fees in 2017. Can I still file my PPA and potentially be granted a patent due to the other patent has expired?

No you cannot obtain a patent for something already publicly disclosed. An expired patent is publicly disclosed. For one thing you haven't invented anything if someone else thought of it first. Since the patent has expired, you can use the technology that was patented so long as no other relevant patents in force.
